# How does this Ruby app know to select the middle third of sentences?

Tags: ruby, slice

I am currently following Beginning Ruby by Peter Cooper and have put together my first app, a text analyzer.  However, whilst I understand all of the concepts and the way in which they work, I can't for the life of me understand how the app knows to select the middle third of sentences sorted by length from this line:

```
ideal_sentances = sentences_sorted.slice(one_third, one_third + 1)
```

I have included the whole app for context any help is much appreciated as so far everything is making sense.

```
#analyzer.rb --Text Analyzer

stopwords = %w{the a by on for of are with just but and to the my I has some in do}
lines = File.readlines(ARGV[0]) 
line_count = lines.size 
text = lines.join 

#Count the characters
character_count = text.length 
character_count_nospaces = text.gsub(/\s+/, '').length

#Count the words, sentances, and paragraphs
word_count = text.split.length 
paragraph_count = text.split(/\n\n/).length 
sentence_count = text.split(/\.|\?|!/).length

#Make a list of words in the text that aren't stop words,
#count them, and work out the percentage of non-stop words
#against all words
all_words = text.scan(/\w+/)
good_words = all_words.select {|word| !stopwords.include?(word)}
good_percentage = ((good_words.length.to_f / all_words.length.to_f)*100).to_i

#Summarize the text by cherry picking some choice sentances
sentances = text.gsub(/\s+/, ' ').strip.split(/\.|\?|!/)
sentances_sorted = sentences.sort_by { |sentence| sentance.length }
one_third = sentences_sorted.length / 3
ideal_sentances = sentences_sorted.slice(one_third, one_third + 1)
ideal_sentances = ideal_sentences.select{ |sentence| sentence =~ /is|are/ }

#Give analysis back to user

puts "#{line_count} lines" 
puts "#{character_count} characters" 
puts "#{character_count_nospaces} characters excluding spaces" 
puts "#{word_count} words" 
puts "#{paragraph_count} paragraphs" 
puts "#{sentence_count} sentences" 
puts "#{sentence_count / paragraph_count} sentences per paragraph (average)" 
puts "#{word_count / sentence_count} words per sentence (average)"
puts "#{good_percentage}% of words are non-fluff words"
puts "Summary:\n\n" + ideal_sentences.join(". ")
puts "-- End of analysis."
```

Obviously I am a beginner so plain English would help enormously, cheers.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Please post the result that you're getting and the result that you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sentences` is a list of all sentences.  `sentances_sorted` is that list sorted by sentence length, so the middle third will be the sentences with the most average length.  `slice()` grabs that middle third of the list, starting from the position represented by `one_third` and counting `one_third + 1` from that point.

Note that the correct spelling is 'sentence' and not 'sentance'.  I mention this only because you have some code errors that result from spelling it inconsistently.

Answer (score 3):

It gets a third of the length of the sentence with `one_third = sentences_sorted.length / 3` then the line you posted `ideal_sentances = sentences_sorted.slice(one_third, one_third + 1)` says "grab a slice of all the sentences starting at the index equal to 1/3rd and continue 1/3rd of the length +1".

Make sense?

Answer (score 2):

The slice method in you look it up in the ruby API say this:

> If passed two Fixnum  objects, returns a substring starting at the
>   offset given by the first, and  a length given by the second.

This means that if you have a sentence broken into three pieces

```
 ONE | TWO | THREE
```

`slice(1/3, 1/3+1)`

will return the string starting at 1/3 from the beginning

```
 | TWO | THREE (this is what you are looking at now)
```

then you return the string that is 1/3+1 distance from where you are, which gives you

```
 | TWO |
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this when I first started too. In plain English, you have to realize that the slice method can take 2 parameters here.

The first is the index. The second is how long slice goes for.

So lets say you start off with 6 sentences.
one_third = 2
slice(one_third, one_third+1)

1/3 of 6 is 2.

1) here the 1/3 means you start at element 2 which is index[1] 
2) then it goes on for 2 (6/3) more + 1 length, so a total of 3 spaces

so it is affecting indexes 1 to index 3